# What does "{%" do in HTML?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've added Django messages to my app using the official documentation. In it it says to add something like this to my template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

I have no idea what the percentage signs do, they're not actual HTML right?

Comment: Even i don't know why people down vote this :)

Comment: Haha me neither but thanks for the answer! I learned Django but I guess I should've gone through the docs more

Comment: It gets downvoted because it is hard to understand how the OP could get this far with their Django project without knowing what Django template tags are.

Comment: May be user try to learn from an existing project :) , may be i am wrong but help if you can.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Not really, its not covered in the main tutorial. Django messages aren't necessary at all for designing a site. I was focusing on the programming more back then and came back to this a month later when I wanted to display a message and I wasn't sure what they were for

Comment: But that's my point, your question has nothing to do with messages specifically. Template tags are fundamental to pretty much anything you do with Django - and definitely are covered in the tutorial - so it's perplexing how you can have done your whole site up to the point of implementing messages but not know about tags.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right, I was just going through it (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03). But it's extremely brief and they more explain what happening between the tags (which is obvious). The actual link to the topic says `Tags are surrounded by {% and %} like this` which I wish was in the main tutorial so I wouldn't be here lol thanks again

Comment: @DanielRoseman You point might not apply to all the context, because you don't see this type of tags very often if you are not working with django. For ex, some of people only use django as a pure backend web service and they have their web frontend developed (whatever vue, react or angular) in a separate project. They don't need these tags in their html or js files.

Comment: Here's a better, more up-to-date resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-template-tags/#:~:text=Tags%20are%20more%20complex%20than,logic%20in%20the%20rendering%20process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a template engine syntax use in html pages, django compile it when you render a view html with a context variable and return a basic html response.

`In your case your message will be your context variable and django engine compile it like` :

> if message is not None then inner part html is visible.

Doc. Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/

Comment: Django does not include Jinja. Jinja is a separate project that was created so that Django template syntax could be used independent of Django.